# vcvarsall.bat not found during Python compilation, checked all possibilities

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++, numpy, pip

I have problem with adding packages to Python (with or without pip).
I think I have checked all the possibilities that I found were discussed here. Anyway, here is the situation:

I have Microsoft Visual C++ compiler installed, including file `vcvarsall.bat` (as wanted by pip). I have correctly set up path variable to the file.

Still, if I want to install downloaded package (numpy), Python yells at me:

```
No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

If I want to get numpy with pip (which otherwise works correctly), it downloads the package, it starts running the installation and than it lags - it continues no further and command prompt stops responding.

I have tried everything many times and have no clue what to do. Can anyone help?

I am running on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Which version of Python? And which version of the Visual C++ compiler do you have installed?

Comment: On Windows, I would recommend to get a pre-build binary installer for numpy (or anything that requires C-extension compilation). pip need to build them during installation and that's usually hard. Unless really necessary, check the official installer (http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/) or ones from C. Gohlke (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)